# Available data on persons charged with human trafficking on the Southwest border?

Tags: united-states, illegal-immigration, immigration-customs-enforcement

One of the justifications offered to support the child separation policy at the SW border is a humanitarian one of liberating children from persons who are bringing children into the US to "sell" or otherwise "enslave" them - aka human traffickers.

Since the zero tolerance policy was rolled out (ca April 2018) approximately 30,000 (alleged) family units were apprehended, along with approximately 15,000 unaccompanied children.

What I can't seem to find is how many persons have been actually charged with human trafficking since April. (Conviction may take longer, but charging ought be rather prompt - so let's limit the scope to  "charging" ).

**Initially** I make no distinction between sex or labor trafficking (which would likely be a major concern to those concerned about the safety of children after arrival). Another category that might fall into the trafficking arena would be persons who are "paid escorts", although this category is (likely) more benign than sex and labor. 
Edit: I will restate this question in Law SE to be more specific, my thanks to commenters

Answer (score 4):

According to this article [How to mislead with statistics, DHS Secretary Nielsen edition](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2018/06/18/how-to-mislead-with-statistics-dhs-secretary-nielsen-edition/) reported on June 18, 2018

> “The kids are being used as pawns by the smugglers and the
>   traffickers,” Nielsen said.
>
> “Again, let’s just pause to think about this statistic: 314 percent
>   increase in adults showing up with kids that are not a family unit,”
>   she said. “Those are traffickers, those are smugglers, that is MS-13,
>   those are criminals, those are abusers.”
>
> A DHS representative provided The Washington Post with the hard
>   numbers behind Nielsen’s statistic. There were 46 cases of fraud —
>   “individuals using minors to pose as fake family units” — in fiscal
>   2017, the period from October 2016 through September 2017. In the
>   first five months of 2018, there were 191 cases.
>
> That is an increase of 315 percent.

It is not immediately clear what the numbers are specifically related to human trafficking arrests, see [U.S. Border Patrol Southwest Border Apprehensions by Sector FY2018](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/stats/usbp-sw-border-apprehensions) for the raw data. According to statistics for 2016 at [Human Trafficking - ICE](https://www.ice.gov/features/human-trafficking)

> In fiscal year 2016, HSI initiated 1,029 investigations with a nexus
>   to human trafficking and recorded 1,952 arrests, 1,176 indictments,
>   and 631 convictions; 435 victims were identified and assisted.

and [Border arrests exceed 50,000 for third month in a row](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/border-arrests-exceed-50000-for-third-month-in-a-row/2018/06/06/db6f15a6-680b-11e8-bea7-c8eb28bc52b1_story.html).

The most recent Bureau of Justice Statistics data as to human trafficking is for 2015 [Federal Prosecution of Human-Trafcking Cases, 2015](https://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/fphtc15.pdf), where the total number was reported to be 1,923 total persons referred for human trafficking prosecution

> In fscal year 2015, 1,923 suspects were referred to U.S. attorneys
>   with human trafcking as the lead charge—39% for peonage, slavery,
>   forced labor or sex trafcking; 32% for production of child
>   pornography; and 29% for transportation for illegal sex activity. This
>   was a 41% increase from the 1,360 suspects referred to U.S. attorneys
>   in 2011.

It is important to note the conflicting reports that have been issued as to the subject matter of human trafficking, see [2018 NCVRW Resource Guide: Human Trafficking Fact Sheet](https://ovc.ncjrs.gov/ncvrw2018/info_flyers/fact_sheets/2018NCVRW_Trafficking_508_QC.pdf)

> In FY 2016, DOJ initiated 241 federal human trafficking prosecutions
>   and charged 531 defendants. Of these prosecutions, nearly 95% were
>   predominantly related to sex trafficking. DOJ also secured convictions
>   against 439 traffickers in FY 2016. Of those convicted, 97% were
>   primarily involved in sex trafficking.

and the disclaimer of the data held within the report

> Human trafficking is difficult to measure. Fear of harm to self or
>   others, language barriers, lack of personal freedom, and fear of law
>   enforcement often prevent victims from reporting their victimization
>   or seeking services. Additionally, multiple agencies are charged with
>   investigating and prosecuting human trafficking cases, at both the
>   federal and state level, and providing services to victims. The
>   record-keeping systems across these agencies may not allow for
>   cross-referencing, and some victims may appear in the records of
>   multiple agencies. Because of this, human trafficking reports should
>   not be used to make generalizations about the scale or scope of human
>   trafficking in the United States.

where "human trafficking" can be divided into at least several categories including "labor trafficking" and "sex trafficking".

It is not clear if the question attempts to distinguish between sex trafficking, labor trafficking, or human trafficking without any forced attached sex or labor after the "victim" or "illegal immigrant", depending on the perspective is successfully trafficked into the United States; for example, a family paying a trafficker to get them to the U.S. without being forced into sex or labor, or if the premise is that all human trafficking involves forced sex and labor.

What is clear is that the total prosecutions for human trafficking arrests at the border is a substantially low percentage of the total "border arrests".

According to [Southwest Border Migration FY2018](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/stats/sw-border-migration) a total of 145393 persons have been apprehended between April 2018 and June 2018. Correlating the total number of individuals charged with human trafficking for the entire year of 2018 to the publication date of the Washington Post article *How to mislead with statistics, DHS Secretary Nielsen edition*, we have 191.

Thus, the math is

`(191 / 145393) * 100 = 0.13136808512101683`

or, 0.1%.

Comment: Is it clear that the 191 cases of suspected fraud were exclusive to the Southwest border? While this answer makes a valiant effort at the question, it still doesn't answer the fundamental question of how many persons have been charged under  8 USC 1324(a)(2)(B)(ii).

Comment: @BobE The article states “individuals using minors to pose as fake family units” are "In the first five months of 2018, there were 191 cases." which indicates all charges. You can check the district courts dockets for 8 USC 1324(a)(2)(B)(ii) charges; file freedom of information requests; write a letter to the Director of the primary agency responsible for the comment referring to the number 191.  The Bureau of Justice Statistics have not yet published 2018 data. To cross reference that data will require a comprehensive study of all the different agency, court, and non-profit organization data.

Comment: @BobE _"FACTS: There were 31,102 “family units” apprehended at the border in the first five months of fiscal year 2018, The Washington Post reported. In that time, there were 191 cases of “individuals using minors to pose as fake family units,” according to DHS. That’s less than 1 percent. And it’s not clear how many, if any, of the cases involved traffickers or gang members"_ https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/trump-administration-lies-immigration-family-separations_us_5b3689cfe4b08c3a8f6a3b73 The 191 number is cited by multiple articles, needs to be further vetted for accuracy.

Comment: I generally agree that off the 191 suspected fraud cases, probably not all were actual trafficking cases. What I'm trying to get a hold of is how many actual SW trafficking charges have been made since zero tolerance.  Perhaps I'm wrong, but referrals (complaints) for violation of the above code would be filed with the US Attorney's office where the violation occurred. It is up to the US Attorney's office to file charges based on the complaint. Now, there are only two US Attorney districts that cover the Southwest border of Texas (as an example). -please continue

Comment: Since those charges are (or should be) public, it would seem a fairly easy task for an enterprising journalist to inquire how many persons have been charged under the code in the last several months.  What I was hoping was - if that inquiry was made  were the results published.

Comment: @BobE Actual charges for violations of U.S. Code need to be filed in federal district court. You can check the court dockets for the specific U.S. Code violation that you refer to in your comment. No, not necessarily an "easy task", as each federal district court's website might be slightly different. Though you are correct in that the charges should be in the public record. You can call or write to the Clerk of the Court - being very specific about your inquiry. Investigative journalism requires investigation, which is labor intensive to acquire data and then check the accuracy of the data.

Comment: The federal district court for the southern district of Texas has a public affairs office. That would be my first stop to inquire. HOWEVER, they will only take inquiries from members of the press (which is why I suggested an enterprising journalist.  (determining the **accuracy**  from that source may be labor intensive)

Comment: @BobE _"HOWEVER, they will only take inquiries from members of the press"_ Source of that statement? The subject matter is not secret indictments. The information should be available through a number of means.

Comment: @BobE https://pcl.uscourts.gov/pcl/index.jsf

Comment: on the website you cited "This is a restricted government website for official PACER use only. Unauthorized entry is prohibited and subject to prosecution under Title 18 of the U.S. Code. All activities and access attempts are logged."    From the TX western district site "The Office of Public Affairs is responsible for ensuring that timely, accurate, and relevant information regarding the prosecution of federal crimes is disseminated to the public.

If you have a press related inquiry.....". I've not dealt with this PAO, most will not take inquiries from the public.

Comment: @BobE Attorneys and paralegals should be able to access the site. The official records (complaints) are in the public domain, unless they are one or more sealed indictments. It is simply a matter of locating them. You can certainly write to the Clerk of the Court as the Public to ask questions. Can you link to the specific page which displays that textual content?

Comment: Yes, but first [http://trac.syr.edu/whatsnew/email.180627.html]  data is stale (end of April) but is a good lead. Here is the Western District PAO page: [https://www.justice.gov/usao-wdtx/policy-and-programs/public-affairs]. Other PAO's I've contacted have flat out told me to contact a local newspaper and have paper ask them. They are not equipped to respond to John Q Public.

Comment: @BobE Both links are bad. Those are ridiculous responses from a district court, or any governmental branch or administrative agency. What do you mean by "told me"? You can also contact (in writing) your Representative and Senators (be very specific). They should reply to you in writing (you are their constituent); they have staff to perform that very task; if you cannot contact the Representative and Senators directly.

Comment: @BobE [Southern District of Texas Immigration Cases Cases by Nature of Suit](https://dockets.justia.com/browse/state-texas/court-txsdce/noscat-14) ; [Southern District of Texas Immigration Cases Other Immigration Actions Cases, Dockets and Filings](https://dockets.justia.com/browse/state-texas/court-txsdce/noscat-14/nos-465)

Comment: Your link worked, however again I ran up against "This is a Restricted Web Site for Official Court Business only". If you can get docket info on any of these cases, you must have already registered with PACER.

Comment: @BobE You should be able to use PACER at the nearest law library to you; e.g., a college or university with a law dept. or main public library in your region. There are services which provide _published_ cases, though what you are trying to acquire is a _complaint_. Now that you have the specific _case names_ and _case numbers_, the Clerk of the Court should be able to respond to your request for the charge in the complaint. Have pulled entire multi-party indictments from district court websites, so the task should be possible, though may not be "easy" or straightforward for the lay person.

Comment: On the bad links: apparently I lost the leading "www." So should be [ http://www.trac.syr.edu/whatsnew/email.180627.html ]  and [ https://www.justice.gov/usao-wdtx/policy-and-programs/public-affairs ] . as to the "told me" - I actually called PAOs (on other matters) in OH, PA, AZ and all stated to me approx the same thing, to wit: there job is limited to responding to the recognized media, NOT the general public. (One clerk of courts in SD actually gave me the name and phone # of the newspaper reporter who could provide data... go figure !)

Comment: @BobE  Those responses are absurd. Depending on how interested you are in this subject matter would definitely consider maintaining documentation of your attempts to retrieve Public information and records. That shows that you have tried to exhaust your administrative remedies before actually filing a lawsuit for the information that you are requesting. Also, bear in mind that just because a case has a habeas corpus heading does not mean that the facts of the case do not revolve around the U.S. Codes that you are interested in. You have to read the cases, without excluding any from your list.

Comment: @BobE Why are you contacting the U.S. Attorney's Office? They are the prosecutor, and are under enormous pressure from their boss and the public. If for some reason you have decided to ask that Office questions, you can do so in written form within certified letter. Now that you have case names and numbers from the Justia website you can contact the Clerk of the Court and the federal public defenders office to ask specific questions. Write your questions and their answers down if you phone. Or write letters and phone.

Comment: Because the Attorney's office is more likely to have the statistics I'm seeking, Just like the BCP and ICE, they are expected to provide statistics to the DOJ on the number and catagories of cases The clerk is does not have to categorize cases.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this information is extremely difficult to find. 
Essentially I was asking for the number of persons charged under 8 USC 1324 (a)(2)(b)(ii) in the last 3-4 months for offenses occuring on the Southwestern US border.

For the sake of clarity 8 USC 1324 (a)(2)(b)(ii) refers to:

> Any person who brings or attempts to bring to the United States an unauthorized alien for the purpose of commercial advantage or private financial gain ( 8 USC 1324 (a) (2) (b) (ii) )

It is the "personal or commercial gain" that generally people understand as "human trafficking"; and that is the basis of the original question

At this time, the closest published data [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2018/06/18/how-to-mislead-with-statistics-dhs-secretary-nielsen-edition/?utm_term=.d84357382a7a) is Secty Nielsen's
191 cases of “individuals using minors to pose as fake family units”.

Perhaps the best that can be said is that human trafficking is a sub-set of that 191 cases.

In conclusion: until the DOJ releases the number of persons charged under 8 USC 1324 (a)(2)(b)(ii) we do not know with any certainty the answer to the original question.

However, I would suppose that if the number were substantial DOJ or DHS will publicize it sooner rather than later.

Comment: Did you give up on further investigation? You have the case names and numbers. You need only read the cases. You do not need to wait on agency statistics to be published.

Comment: I can read the cases if I pay 6.00 per case.  The public library has no subscription to PACER, the local law library would provide access, however they are contractually required to charge 6.00 per case. It might be different if my list of cases was filtered to just those where the lead charge 8usc1324(a)(2)(b)(ii), but it is not. I'd have to buy and read all ~800 cases.  I do have one other lead, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Have you contacted the Clerk of the Court and the Federal Public Defenders Office?